# IOS - UIScrollView Refusing to scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have built a large IOS app and whilst testing noticed that a uiScrollview within a static page has stopped scrolling - to explain the setup of the page - the structure is as follows -

[image]

the scrollview is connected to the header file as scwollMa (as in above doc).

it has the following properties in storyboard -

[image]

[image]

I have applied the following into the .m page -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set Scroller
    [_scwollMa setScrollEnabled:YES];


    self.scwollMa.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1100);
```

Yet it does nothing!  no error either - big head scratcher!  Any advice at all?

Comment: maybe try disconnecting and reconnecting the IBOutlet

Comment: cheers @chetem - tried but no glory unfortunately

Comment: does it work without UITextView?

Answer (score 2):

You have set the height of the scrollview at the same height as the content size. To scroll set the height of the scroll view to fit into the visible screen area (like self.view.frame.size.height).
If the scroll view and the content view have the same height, there's nothing to scroll for.

Comment: so your saying something like  self.scwollMa.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); should do the job?

Comment: self.scwollMa.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+(some integer value));

Comment: what integer value you have added in height ?

Comment: i added -     self.scwollMa.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+1100);

Comment: Please understand - your problem is NOT the CONTENT SIZE.
Your problem is: Your scroll view is LARGER than your iPhone or iPad screen size. 
so your SCROLL VIEW SIZE should be SMALLER than your SCREEN SIZE.
You do NOT scroll the SCROLL VIEW, you DO SCROLL the CONTENT INSIDE the scrollview.
So please set the CONTENT SIZE to the size of your CONTENT and the SCROLL VIEW SIZE to the size of your SCREEN.

Comment: cool ok cheers @BernhardGrabowski I understand the concept - it just didnt work when applied - I finally discovered that my issue is to do with Autolayout which i had applied for iPad layout and was stopping the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

contentSize.Height must be greater to actual.height: 
Change the following line of code to

```
 self.scwollMa.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1500);
```

will work for you.

and in interface builder keep height which is visible inside your view.

[image]

Comment: But the scroll view itself will still be way offscreen, wouldn't it?

Comment: Height of scrollview must be less than or equal to your view height for visibility. we can increase the content size as per needed.

Comment: just go to interface builder and set scrollview height less than your self.view's height